# Mongoose querying with a date field without time

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a record in mongodb that has date field

```
createdAt: 2021-08-03T19:52:00.000+00:00
```

from our API client we receive date in mm/dd/yyyy format for example

```
date: "08/03/2021"
```

Upon creating the Date object in javascript `new Date("08/03/2021")` it changes the ISODate to

```
`2021-08-02T20:00:00.000Z`.
```

Hence the document doesn't fall under the required date range.

example query

```
{createdAt: {'$lt': new Date('08/03/2021')}}
```

Considering that I can do alteration on database level, what are my options to overcome this issue.

Thanks Much.

Comment: Are you storing that "createdAt" field as a Date or as a String? You wont be able to do that query unless you save it as Date

Comment: It is stored as Date @RubénVega

Comment: Then it may be because of local time diferences. When you made the new Date() is converted to UTC, and as you can see is a day before. Maybe your query is executing in another local time? Could you check to what UTC time is converted in the query?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) library:

```
{createdAt: {
    $gt: moment("08/03/2021", "MM/DD/YYYY").startOf('day').toDate(),
    $lt: moment("08/03/2021", "MM/DD/YYYY").endOf('day').toDate(),
    }
}
```

Comment: TypeError: moment(...).beginOf is not a function

Comment: @AshadNasim sorry was my mistake. Must be `startOf`

Comment: I had used some other approach, but thanks anyway, it will help other developers